# What makes a MacBook much thicker or thinner?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, hardware

Apple's official website says the height of a MacBook could be from "0.35 to 1.31 cm". This is a wide range, more than double thickness.

I'm buying a new customized MacBook. When is it 0.35 cm thick and when is it 1.31 cm, for example when increasing storage or changing CPU?

Comment: Enjoy your new machine :)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The case is tapered.

[image]

It's thicker at the back than the front.

Pic from [Apple Store - Macbook](https://www.apple.com/macbook/)

Comment: Aha, so It isn't a range based on more hardware or storage

Comment: No, it's simply an aesthetic feature common to many Apple devices; makes them look very sleek.

Comment: It's also bigger on the inside.

Comment: It's really a lap-sized TARDIS.

Comment: It's a clown car, but for silicon.

Comment: I *wish* we had magic metal boxes that could change dimensions depending on what we put inside them. That would be *so cool* ...

Comment: No no no. See, it's literally a question of "when is it thicker/thinner?" Its thickness changes over time with the new Mojave Dynamic Desktops feature (so you have to enable that). Over the morning, when the colors become brighter and warmer, the MacBook "rises" as well, i.e. becomes thicker. Near the evening it becomes thinner again as it "lays down" and when it enters sleep mode, it lies flat (as you should do in bed) at its thinnest.

Comment: This is starting to remind me of [Monty Python - Theory on Brontosauruses by Anne Elk (Miss).](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U6zWjUhfj-M)

Comment: @DarthFennec we have them. They are called "bags". (And yes, they are sometimes made out of metal).